# Deleting, Adding and Editing elements in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using WebSockets, (socket.io) I have an app with more than one room each room needs to show the usernames of each user in that room and their score so I need to keep track of username, score and current room (username and room number are also stored in sockets sessions but need to be stored in the array too). I wish to access, add, delete and edit the array using the username as the main reference point.

my array:

```
var users = [];
```

structure:

```
[
    {
        "nickname": [
            "usernickname"
        ],
        "inroom": 1,
        "score": 0
    },
    {
        "nickname": [
            "usernickname"
        ],
        "inroom": 1,
        "score": 0
    }
]
```

How i've been adding to it:

```
function addEntry(nickname, inroom, score){
  users.push({
    nickname: nickname,
    inroom: inroom,
    score: score
  });
}


addEntry(["usernickname"],1,0);
```

Attempting to delete via nickname, I know this works `delete users[1];` but I would need to know what position the nickname was in the array to delete via the nickname tried this  `delete users.nickname[usernickname];` didn't work, I tried a few `.splice` methods but I couldn't get them to work either...

I thought at one point .`indexOf` OR `Array.prototype.indexOf()` could be of help to finding the position of nickname(s) to be removed/edited but again had no luck using it with what I had.

Comment: To delete an item, you have to loop through the array searching for the nickname, there is no other option.

Comment: So which part of the "adding, editing and deleting" are you having problem with may I ask?

Comment: Also, you are using variables with the same names as the object property names.  So you will need to quote your property names: ie. `'nickname': nickname`.

Comment: marked as duplicate but only half the question answered how can I update certain element based on nickname